# Fit nonlinear parameter

Tags: r, modeling, nonlinear-regression

I'm attempting to fit this model:

$P = C_0 + C_1*U^r$

Given known vectors of observations $P$ and $U$, I want to fit values for $C_0$, $C_1$ and $r$.

How do I make this fit in R? or preferably GSL in C?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's certainly possible to fit nonlinear models in R

However, what you haven't specified is the error term - your observed data don't lie exactly on such a curve. So your actual model for the observed data is something like

$$P = C_0 + C_1\cdot U^r +\varepsilon\,,$$

where $\varepsilon$ is the error (or noise) term that explains the difference between the curve and the data.

What particularly matters* is how the variability of the noise term changes with $U$.

*(this is, unfortunately, all too often neglected, often leading to unrecognized problems)

In the situation where $\text{Var}(\varepsilon)$ is constant, ordinary nonlinear regression using least squares may be suitable.

This sort of model is standard in most stats packages and may be fitted in R via the `nls` function.

The GSL in C has similar functionality. See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Nonlinear-Least_002dSquares-Fitting.html#Nonlinear-Least_002dSquares-Fitting).

---

```
pudat = data.frame(u = c(0.05554, 0.13616, 0.29995, 0.4842, 0.64244, 0.8561, 
                         1.06265, 1.12101, 1.34655, 1.38817, 1.64635, 1.86313), 
                   p = c(1.86312, 2.26092, 2.87106, 3.48917, 4.17016, 5.77962, 
                         7.67722, 7.96844, 9.84074, 10.76704, 13.04834, 15.22215))
```

We need some starting guesses for the parameters. It's not very sensitive to them, but lets start with C0 just a little smaller than the minimum value (since our x-range takes us down close to it, and then subtract that guess at c0 and take logs and fit a linear model to get starting values for the other two parameters:

```
c0start = 1.8

> stt=lm(log(p-c0start)~log(u),pudat)$coefficients
> stt
(Intercept)      log(u) 
   1.674318    1.440003     

powrfit=nls(p~c0+c1*u^r,pudat,start=list(c0=c0start,c1=exp(1.67),r=1.44))

> summary(powrfit)

Formula: p ~ c0 + c1 * u^r

Parameters:
   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
c0  1.90169    0.13824   13.76 2.39e-07 ***
c1  5.09912    0.18298   27.87 4.79e-10 ***
r   1.55971    0.05296   29.45 2.93e-10 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.2041 on 9 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations to convergence: 3 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 8.396e-06
```

Now lets look at the fit:

```
x = seq(.05,15.5,.05)
fit = 1.90169 + 5.09912 * x ^ 1.55971  # normally use the predict function for this

plot(p~u,pudat)
lines(x,fit,col=3)
```

[image]

---

If the spread of the error term was (say) increasing with $E(P)$, then this wouldn't be directly suitable (indeed, the estimated standard errors would be biased), and a different model would be needed. For example, a model like $\log P = \log(C_0 + C_1\cdot U^r) +\varepsilon\,$ might have stable variance, but then we might have to worry about the fcat that $E(P)\neq \exp(E(\log(P))$ - if the bias in the expectation matters we'd have to adjust for that.

Comment: I just updated my answer to briefly mention the existence of the equivalent in GSL and to link to the part of the manual that relates to it.

Comment: Thank you. I'll attempt to apply this on Monday. Then I'll likely mark this as the correct answer.